# Wrapper for nested dictionary

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, wrapper

I have nested dictionary implementation like this:

```
Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>
```

Now I am using this at many places in my project, 
but I feel ugly writing such a long name every time for example:

```
Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>> obj1=new Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>();
Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>> obj2=new Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>();
Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>> obj3=new Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>();
```

Could I make some wrapper for this dictionary so that I can just write it like this to make it more readable:

```
MyWrapper obj1=new MyWrapper();
MyWrapper obj2=new MyWrapper();
MyWrapper obj3=new MyWrapper();
```

Comment: Excellent class name! /s
Seven years on, what would you name this abstraction now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper once, lets see, [here](https://sharpkom.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/sharpkom/SharpKom/MultipleKeyDictionary.cs) it is.

You can access an element by two keys like this `dictionary["key1", "key2"]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a wrapper you can create an alias in the top of your .cs-file

```
using MyWrapper = 
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Namespace.class1,
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Namespace.class2>>;
```

This is particularly useful if you are interacting with other classes (that you don't control) that expect this long types. Then you can use a handy name in your files, but it is really an alias for the full type.

Both the following uses are equivalent.

```
MyWrapper w1 = new MyWrapper();
MyWrapper w2 = new Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could:

```
public class MyWrapper : Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>
{}
```

Of course, you can add some methods to this wrapper that simplify lookups and inserts (and any other functionality needed).

Alternatively, you could use the [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword to reduce some of the "noise", without introducing a wrapper:

```
var obj1 = new Dictionary<class1, Dictionary<int, class2>>();
```

Or, a combination...

```
var obj1 = new MyWrapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic wrapper class but I wouldn't say that this would perform the clearness of the code. Plus you would have to write methods that provide access to the internal dictionaries.

```
public class MyWrapper<T1, T2, T3>
{
    private IDictionary<T1, IDictionary<T2, T3>> dictionary;

    public MyWrapper()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<T1, IDictionary<T2, T3>>();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myWrapper = new MyWrapper<int, string, bool>();
    }
}
```